# Selenium throws timeout after locating the element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Has anyone experienced the problem when the webdriver locates the needed element, types the text into it, and then throws WebDriverTimeout exception saying that it takes too much time to find the exact same element that it has just sent text into? 
If I wrap this block of code in try-catch which catches the timeout exception, the test goes on successfully, but it doesn't seem to be the healthy way of doing this.

I am using the c# selenium and chromedriver 2.44

**Update:**
The initial wait configuration and the action itself:

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

...
var searchLocator = By.Id("searchByName");
driver.GetElement(searchLocator, 20, element => element.Displayed).SendKeys("test");
```

GetElement extension:

```
public static IWebElement GetElement(this IWebDriver driver, By locator, double timeout, Func<IWebElement, bool> condition)
{
  var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
  wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(StaleElementReferenceException));
  wait.Until(drv =>
    { 
      var element = driver.FindElement(locator);
      return condition(element);
    });

   return driver.FindElement(locator);
}
```

StackTrace:

```
Result StackTrace:    
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.SendKeys(String text)
at Tests.Steps.SearchSteps.WhenTheUserFillsTheSearchFieldWith(String searchFieldName, String data) in C:\...Tests\Steps\SearchSteps.cs:line 64
at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager , String , String )
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors()
at Tests.Features.SearchFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
at Tests.Features.SearchFeature.CheckSearch() in C:\...Tests\Features\Search.feature:line 167
Result Message:    
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : timeout
(Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.110)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538
(b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

Comment: Post your code and the compete stacktrace.

Comment: Update the question with relevant _HTML_, _code trials_ and _error stack trace_

Comment: Error can happen for lots of reasons.  It is best to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to capture data.  From the error you can't tell if nothing go returned.  Also with http you need to check the status and see if you got 200 Done.  http has both 1.0 (stream mode) and 1.1 (chunk mode).  Chunk mode requires you to send a next chunk message and if you do not send the next chunk then you get a timeout.

Comment: On which line does the error throw? Stacktrace is not helpful as GetElement does not appear in it.

Comment: @Meta-Knight It seems that it breaks on SendKeys() part of the step

Comment: @jdweng Do I understand you correctly that it is possible to monitor Selenium session using fiddler? I have tried it, but apparently missed some pre-configurations, because the session does not show up in fiddler

Comment: Any web connection can be monitored with fiddler.  The filters for fiddler may be set wrong.  A web connection uses TCP as the transport layer.  So I would monitor TCP and HTTP.  An http message consists of one or more TCP packets.  The TCP may not be completing and that is why you are not seeing any HTTP.

Comment: @raido: You should validate which line throws the error otherwise it is hard to help. Also, I don't understand how the test can pass with a try-catch if the SendKeys is essential to the test. It seems like we don't have all the info here.

Comment: @Meta-Knight Sorry, I mean driver.GetElement(searchLocator, 20, element => element.Displayed).SendKeys("test"); is the line which throws the error. It is just the last part of it with SendKeys() which causes the error in the current case.

Comment: @Meta-Knight As for the try-catch, the point is - that Selenium types the text into the input as though everything works okay and then throws the exception. So if I ignore exception, all the needed actions are performed and the test proceeds to another step. But for some reason Selenium doesn't get to know that the operation is completed.

Comment: @raido: That is strange, I have never seen such behavior with SendKeys.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set various timeout spans using the manage method on the driver. One of these should do the trick:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
```

Also you are able to specify timeout in the ctor like:

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver (pathToDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds (30))
```

In the constructor case, the timeout is the command timeout that . Not sure which one is appropriate for you. Probably what you need is the implicitwait tho.